# Unable to applybindings after cleanNode

Tags: knockout.js

I have the below code and it is fine when the first time I have some value in 'msg'. But, when the script is run second time, when there is no 'msg', it is also fine. the issue is third time when I run it again, it is not binding the value and it is not rendering my span in html. here is the code. Please let me know what Im missing.

```
    var msg = '';
if (splitArray._latestValue != null) {
msg = splitArray._latestValue[1].concat(" was merged to ",splitArray._latestValue[2], ".");
}
var loyaltyIdModel = {
    loyaltyMessage: ko.observable(msg)
}
ko.applyBindings(loyaltyIdModel, document.getElementById("loyaltyId"));
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("loyaltyId"));
```

I finally ended up fixing by this which doesnt feel good.

```
var msg = 'notmerged';
if (splitArray._latestValue != null) {
    msg = splitArray._latestValue[1].concat(" was merged to ", splitArray._latestValue[2], ".");
}
var loyaltyIdModel = {
    loyaltyMessage: ko.observable('notmerged')
}

loyaltyIdModel.loyaltyMessage(msg);

ko.applyBindings(loyaltyIdModel, document.getElementById("loyaltyId"));
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("loyaltyId"));


<div id="loyaltyId" class="alert-info" data-bind="if: loyaltyMessage() !== 'notmerged'">
    <span data-bind="text: loyaltyMessage"> </span>
</div>
```

here is the latest update n the code. I was able to do it without using cleanNode. Thanks.

```
var viewModel = ko.dataFor(getSearchPanelNode());
var tempModel = ko.dataFor(document.getElementById("loyaltyId"))

if (viewModel) {
    viewModel.result.setItems(model.result.items);
    tempModel.loyaltyMessage(msg);
}
else {
    applyViewModel(model);
    var loyaltyIdModel = {
        loyaltyMessage: ko.observable()
    };
    loyaltyIdModel.loyaltyMessage(msg);
    ko.applyBindings(loyaltyIdModel, document.getElementById("loyaltyId"));
}
```

Comment: This is possibly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you feel you need to use `cleanNode` and call `applyBindings` again?

Comment: there is a another model bound to the view and I have to bind something out of it and it changes for each 'search' on the view. If I dont do it, i get the error 'cannot apply multiple bindings'.

Comment: It sounds like you need an overarching viewmodel that you can apply just once, then update observable values on that.  Whilst I'm aware of `cleanNode` and the ability to call `applyBindings` more than once, I've never had to use it in production code.

Comment: I am not aware of overarching viewmodel and will further dig into it. Thanks.

Comment: if you have access to the base viewmodel, you can just subscribe to the observable `splitArray.subscribe(function (val) { msg = val; });`.  If I understand you

Comment: the base viewmodel does have the splitArray. It is something I built based on some rows returned.

Comment: here is the final code. I did it without cleanNode..yay..

Comment: @Priyaaa You should post that as an answer rather than an edit to the question